# Use LINQ to find complex combinations of items in two lists

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

This question is very similar to a previous question of mine, [Use LINQ to count the number of combinations existing in two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065764/use-linq-to-count-the-number-of-combinations-existing-in-two-lists), except with some further twists.

I have a list of `CartItem`s that can receive a discount based on the items specified in the list of `DiscountItem`s.  I need to be able to pull out the items in the Cart that can receive a discount and apply the appropriate discount specfied in the `DiscountItem`.  The discount is only applied for each combination that exists.  Here's what the two lists might look like to before the discount is applied:

```
    BEFORE DISCOUNT:   

    CartItems                               DiscountItems
    ==============================          ===========================
    SKU     Qty    DiscountApplied          SKU     DiscountAmount
    ==============================          ===========================
    Ham     2      $0.00                    Ham     $0.33
    Bacon   1      $0.00                    Bacon   $2.00
    Ham     1      $0.00                 
    Bacon   2      $0.00
    Cheese  1      $0.00
    Bacon   1      $0.00
```

The tricky part is that it's not simply a matter of joining the two lists together or counting the number of combinations.  The discount is applied for all combinations of `DiscountItem`s that appears in the list of `CartItem`s.  There are 3 such combinations in the above example and if you were to apply the discount for the 3 combinations iteratively across the list, the data would look like the following each time the discount is applied:

```
    After 1st Discount is applied:

    CartItems                               DiscountItems
    ==============================          ===========================
    SKU     Qty    DiscountApplied          SKU     DiscountAmount
    ==============================          ===========================
    Ham     2      $0.33                    Ham     $0.33
    Bacon   1      $2.00                    Bacon   $2.00
    Ham     1      $0.00                 
    Bacon   2      $0.00
    Cheese  1      $0.00
    Bacon   1      $0.00    

    After 2nd Discount is applied:

    CartItems                               DiscountItems
    ==============================          ===========================
    SKU     Qty    DiscountApplied          SKU     DiscountAmount
    ==============================          ===========================
    Ham     2      $0.66                    Ham     $0.33
    Bacon   1      $2.00                    Bacon   $2.00
    Ham     1      $0.00                 
    Bacon   2      $2.00
    Cheese  1      $0.00
    Bacon   1      $0.00        

    After 3rd Discount is applied:

    CartItems                               DiscountItems
    ==============================          ===========================
    SKU     Qty    DiscountApplied          SKU     DiscountAmount
    ==============================          ===========================
    Ham     2      $0.66                    Ham     $0.33
    Bacon   1      $2.00                    Bacon   $2.00
    Ham     1      $0.33                 
    Bacon   2      $4.00
    Cheese  1      $0.00
    Bacon   1      $0.00
```

In the end, everything gets a discount except for the cheese and the extra bacon.  The cheese doesn't get discounted because it's not a discounted item in the list.  The extra bacon doesn't get a discount because it doesn't have a corresponding ham item to qualify for a discount combination.  There are a total of 3 hams and 4 bacons, so one of the bacons is not going to get a discount.

I imagine I should be able to solve this problem using LINQ because it involves enumerating over 2 separate lists, but I can't think of what LINQ methods I would use to make this happen.  The end result of the LINQ query should be the collection of `CartItem`s with the discount having been applied.

Comment: Are you allowed to aggregate your cart items?

Comment: @Nick I wish I could, but no.  That would have been my first approach and obviously would have made the problem a lot easier to solve.

Comment: I am curious about your business rules here. You note that the cheese and "extra bacon" would not have a discount applied. Why? The rules don't seem to make sense, given that Ham and Bacon both get discounts. Clarification of your business rules would help in formulating a solution.

Comment: @jrista Good point.  The business rule is that the discounted items receive a discount for each occurence of the combination in the cart.  So 3 hams + 4 bacons will make 3 combinations that qualify for a discount and will leave 1 bacon without a discount. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for the clarification. Next question: Is there some reason this processing has to be LINQ? There are existing design patterns that might solve this problem better.

Comment: @jrista It doesn't *have* to be entirely in LINQ, but since I anticipate enumerating over both lists to arrive at the solution, I imagine LINQ has a valid place somewhere in the solution.  By all means, though, if there are better patters for solving this problem, I'm open to hearing them.

Comment: @Ben: I am assuming there are any variety of discount combinations, correct? If so, then any particular LINQ solution will only solve the problem for a single kind of discount. I guess my fundamental concern here is you are solving the complexity of only a single kind of discount, rather than the problem of applying a variety of different kinds of discounts to carts. It is probably possible to solve this particular discount with LINQ, as well as procedurally...however *is* there a larger-scale architectural issue applying discounts of various kinds?

Comment: @jrista Well, there is a possibility of applying multiple groups at a time, but I was going to handle that iteratively since it was only going to be about 4 or 5 pairs of items at most. Our design for this particular solution came from the business' decision to simplify their discounting rules compared to how a separate business unit had implemented discounting.

Comment: @Ben: The iterative approach is difficult to do with LINQ, as that is not what LINQ does. It simply builds a query that returns a result set. It sounds like you are trying to force-fit a multi-step iterative process into a query, and I do not think that is possible. You might be able to figure out a way to twist LINQ around to get you a result set that can then be processed in a single pass...but it would be very convoluted. I'll try to provide an example of what I would do when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

OK, just for fun, here's a sort-of-LINQ solution.

It's probably nowhere near as readable or efficient as the equivalent iterative code, but it works!

```
var discountedCart = CartItems.Select(c => c);

var combinations = DiscountItems.Any()
    ? DiscountItems.GroupJoin(CartItems, d => d.SKU, c => c.SKU, (d, g) => g.Sum(c => c.Qty)).Min()
    : 0;

if (combinations > 0)
{
    var map = DiscountItems.ToDictionary(d => d.SKU, d => combinations);

    discountedCart = CartItems.Select(c =>
        {
            int mul;
            map.TryGetValue(c.SKU, out mul);

            if (mul < 1)
                return c;

            decimal amt = DiscountItems.Single(d => d.SKU == c.SKU).DiscountAmount;
            int qty = Math.Min(mul, c.Qty);

            map[c.SKU] = mul - qty;
            return new CartItem { SKU = c.SKU, Qty = c.Qty, DiscountApplied = amt * qty };
        });
}

foreach (CartItem item in discountedCart)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SKU={0} Qty={1} DiscountApplied={2}", item.SKU, item.Qty, item.DiscountApplied);
}
```

(I suspect that if you wanted a single LINQ query with no side-effects then you could wrap it all up in an [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) call, but that would necessitate further depths of ugliness and inefficiency.)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Here we get all items have discounted, and gets minimal count of items
// This value is number of full combinations of items discounted
var minimalNumberOfItemsDiscounted =
CartItems.Where(ci => DiscountItems.Any(di => ci.SKU == di.SKU))
         .GroupBy(ci => ci.SKU)
         .Min(g => g.Count());

// Now we can apply discount to each item in cart, and we know how many 
// times (== minimalNumberOfItemsDiscounted) discount is applied

return CartItems
    .Select(ci => new 
    {
        CartItem = ci, 
        Discount = DiscountItems.FirstOrDefault(di => di.SKU == ci.SKU)
    })
    .Select(k =>
    { 
        if (k.Discount != null)
        {
            k.CartItem.Discount = minimalNumberOfItemsDiscounted * k.Discount.DiscountAmount;
        }
        return k.CartItem;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To get exactly the result you want is bit difficult.You may have to store intermediate result - so need to introduce a new class. This was challenging so I did it as below - it seems to work

```
class Program {
    public class CartItem {
            public string sku { get; set; }
            public int qty {get;set;}
            public decimal DiscountApplied { get; set; }
            public CartItem(string sku,int qty,decimal DiscountApplied) {
                this.sku=sku;
                this.qty=qty;
                this.DiscountApplied=DiscountApplied;
            }
        }
 public class DiscountItem{
   public string sku {get;set;}
   public decimal DiscountAmount {get; set;}
}
static List<CartItem> carts=new List<CartItem>(){
new CartItem("Ham",2,0.0m ),
new CartItem("Bacon",1,0.00m  ),
new CartItem("Ham",1,0.00m ),
new CartItem("Bacon",2 ,0.00m),
new CartItem("Cheese",1,0.00m),
new CartItem("Bacon" , 1 ,  0.00m  )};

static  List<DiscountItem> discounts=new List<DiscountItem>() {
    new DiscountItem(){ sku="Ham", DiscountAmount=0.33m},
    new DiscountItem(){sku="Bacon",DiscountAmount=2.0m}};

class cartsPlus
{
    public CartItem Cart { get; set; }
    public int AppliedCount { get; set; }
}
public static void Main(string[] args){
    int num = (from ca in discounts
               join cart in carts on ca.sku equals cart.sku
               group cart by ca.sku into g
               select new { Sku = g.Key, Num = g.Sum(x => x.qty) }).Min(x => x.Num);

    var cartsplus = carts.Select(x => new cartsPlus { Cart = x, AppliedCount = 0 }).ToList();

    discounts.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(1, num).Select(y => x)).ToList().ForEach(x=>{cartsPlus c=cartsplus.
            First(z=> z.Cart.sku==x.sku&&z.AppliedCount<z.Cart.qty);c.AppliedCount++;c.Cart.DiscountApplied+=x.DiscountAmount;});

     foreach (CartItem c in carts)
       Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}   {2}", c.sku,c.qty, c.DiscountApplied);
}
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I just realized how old this question was.

I personally would use the following because it is the most readable to me. It doesn't use a whole lot of Linq, but I believe it's the least complex answer.

```
// For each discount that can be applied
foreach(var discount = DiscountedItems.Where(c => CartItems.Any(d => d.SKU == c.SKU)))
{
    var discountLimit = 3; // how many items are allowed to have a discount.
    foreach(var item in CartItems.Where(d => d.SKU == item.SKU))
    {
        if(discountLimit < item.Quantity)
        {
            // update the discount applied
            item.DiscountApplied = discountLimit * discount.DiscountAmount;
            discountLimit = 0; // causes the rest of the items to not get a discount
        }
        else
        {
            // update the discount applied
            item.DiscountApplied = item.Qty * discount.DiscountAmount;
            discountLimit -= item.Qty;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have MoreLinq or LinqKit, you can also do the following:

```
// For each discount that can be applied
DiscountedItems.Where(c => CartItems.Any(d => d.SKU == c.SKU)).foreach(discount => 
{
    var discountLimit = 3; // how many items are allowed to have a discount.
    CartItems.Where(d => d.SKU == item.SKU).foreach(item =>
    {
        if(discountLimit < item.Quantity)
        {
            // update the discount applied
            item.DiscountApplied = discountLimit * discount.DiscountAmount;
            discountLimit = 0; // causes the rest of the items to not get a discount
        }
        else
        {
            // update the discount applied
            item.DiscountApplied = item.Qty * discount.DiscountAmount;
            discountLimit -= item.Qty;
        }
    });
});
```